# Cómo hago una imagen más pequeña en Java Script

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer más pequeña una imagen con Java Script?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio. Sugiero que muestres el contenido de la imagen (código HTML)  y lo que has investigado/intentado desde JS para hacer lo que quieres y qué dificultad tienes con el código.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? ¿A tamaño o a dimensiones?

Comment: A. Cedano se refiere al código que has escrito. ¿Qué has investigado al respecto?

Comment: El objetivo es hacer pequeña una imagen con un If-else en Java Script. El antecedente es este: 
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {


    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById ("smart_thumbnail");
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener ("click", function () {

        var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById ("smart_thumbnail");
        thumbnailElement.className = "";
    });



});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con javascript puedes darle un formato de salida, asignandole un width al css de la imagen y así fuerzas el tamaño.

```
<img id="foto" src="..."@>
<script> document.getElementById("foto").style="width: 35px;";
</script>
```